# Scrape a table#id columns with Web::Scraper

Tags: perl

Have a html-page, with a structure:

- have a table with an `id="searchResult"`
- many rows
- each  contains 3 `td` - without any class
- In each table cell contains one URL, and I need the URL from the *second* cell (column)

Tried different XPATH scrapers like:

```
my $links = scraper {
    process '//table[id="searchResult"]', "lines[]" => scraper {
        process "//tr/td[2]/a", text => 'TEXT';
        process "//tr/td[2]/a", link => '@href';
    };
};
my $res = $links->scrape($html);
```

But not works and the $res is an empty `{}`.

If someone needs, here is the full test code:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

use Web::Scraper;
use Data::Dumper;

my $links = scraper {
    process '//table[id="searchResult"]', "lines[]" => scraper {
        process "//tr/td[2]/a", text => 'TEXT';
        process "//tr/td[2]/a", link => '@href';
    };
};

my $html = do {local $/;<DATA>};
#say $html;

my $res = $links->scrape($html);
say Dumper $res;

__DATA__
<html>
<body>
<p>...</p>
<table id="searchResult">
    <thead><th>x</th><th>x</th><th>x</th><th>x</th><th>x</th></thead>
    <tr>
    <td><a href="#11">cell11</a></td>
    <td><a href="#12">cell12</a></td>
    <td><a href="#13">cell13</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><a href="#21">cell21</a></td>
    <td><a href="#22">cell22</a></td>
    <td><a href="#23">cell23</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><a href="#31">cell31</a></td>
    <td><a href="#32">cell32</a></td>
    <td><a href="#33">cell33</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preferred scraper for this type of project is [`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM).  For a helpful 8 minute introductory video, check out [Mojocast Episode 5](http://mojocasts.com/e5).

You also could probably use a pointer to a [CSS Selector Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

The following performs the parsing you're trying to do with this module:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::DOM;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new(do {local $/; <DATA>});

for my $link ($dom->find('table[id=searchResult] > tr > td:nth-child(2) > a')->each) {
    print $link->{href}, " - ", $link->text, "\n";
}

__DATA__
<html>
<body>
<p>...</p>
<table id="searchResult">
    <thead><th>x</th><th>x</th><th>x</th><th>x</th><th>x</th></thead>
    <tr>
    <td><a href="#11">cell11</a></td>
    <td><a href="#12">cell12</a></td>
    <td><a href="#13">cell13</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><a href="#21">cell21</a></td>
    <td><a href="#22">cell22</a></td>
    <td><a href="#23">cell23</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><a href="#31">cell31</a></td>
    <td><a href="#32">cell32</a></td>
    <td><a href="#33">cell33</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Outputs:

```
#12 - cell12
#22 - cell22
#32 - cell32
```

Comment: Sill wondering what is wrong in my XPath definitions, but good to know the Mojo::Dom too. If noone will answer my question will accept this.  +1 and thank you.

Comment: The Mojo::DOM is really wonderful - extremely easy to use. Throwing away Web::Scraper (for now) and accepting this. Thank you again. ;)